# How to make DataGrid columns start from right side Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have data-grid of material ui in my project, and I want to change the style from left to right of all columns and every column start from right side 
this is the [SandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/0wmud)

Answer (score 0):

I find my answer

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
dataGrid: {
  direction: 'rtl',
},
}));
<DataGrid rows={rows} columns={columns} pageSize={5} checkboxSelection className={classes.dataGrid} />
```

Answer (score 0):

I will give my answer, it will be good for you:
But this will not be good when you converted all the table to rtl
in this case will convert the table data without the header.

these classes are responsible for the header, data in each cell in the DataGrid.

```
.tableHeaderStyle{
    direction: rtl;
}
.tableCellStyle{
    direction: rtl;
}
// until now you converted the text to the right of celle.
```

If I found anything else I will update this again.